# How do I add a webform to my Event content type View

Tags: 7, views, webforms

I'm using the Date module to create custom Event content types.  I'm using Webform to create registration forms for each event.  I've created a View that displays events in a table based on start date/end date.  I would like to add a link to the corresponding webform to the event in the View. Is there a way to do that? (Using D7 with all modules updated.) I thought I would need a relationship, but the webform is not available.

Comment: How does Drupal know which webform belongs to which event?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a node reference field on the event?

Example:

1. Create your registration webform and save it.
2. Create your Event node, and in the node reference field select the Webform that will book your event.
3. In your table view you should be able to link to this referenced node.